# How to get the height of Mac unified title and toolbar in Qt/C++

Tags: macos, qt, toolbar, titlebar

I have a Qt 4.7.4 with C++ app that uses the unified title and toolbar on Mac:
    `setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);`
At some point while my app is running, I need to know programmatically what the height of the unified title and toolbar is.

How can I get its height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least with Qt 4.8.4 and Mountain Lion, this looks a bit buggy:

With toolbar on, `QMainWindow::frameGeometry()` reports wrong y position but correct **total** window size. Its `height()` minus `QMainWindow::geometry()`'s `height()` is the height of title bar *and* unified toolbar together in my tests. To find out how tall the toolbar alone is, you could hide it and use the difference.

The Qt people working on this seem to have a few problems and have discontinued `QMainWindow::setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac()`:

> > The unified toolbar implementation from Qt 4 has not and will not be ported
> >     to Qt 5. This means calling QMainWindow::setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac has
> >     no effect on Qt 5. A replacement API which wraps NSToolbar is available in
> >     QtMacExtras.